# background size: contain across different screen

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

How can I display a background image such that the same portion of the image will be shown no matter what's the device screen?

[image]

My current code:

```
body {background:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/k2o673ydhy7tmcu/background-img.jpg');background-size:contain;background-position:center center;background-attachment:fixed;background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

But at smaller screen device, the background is eaten up, only a very small portion is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Ik think your looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vLzzvxv2/

```
body {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/k2o673ydhy7tmcu/background-img.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

article {
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I think this is the solution, I cannot find a way to use background-size: contain to achieve the same effect.